# How to call coffeescript function with parameter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, coffeescript

I created a coffescript function with parameters that looks like this:

```
enlargeSelectionOn : (zoneSelected) ->
  $(zoneSelected).stop().animate 
    width:450
    height:510
    1000
```

The html part looks like this :

```
 #container1
    .title1
        img(src="img/team.png")
        span.text First Title
        a(href="#")
```

And the CSS part (with stylus) looks like

```css
#container1
  width 398px
  height 490px
  float left
  margin-right 11px
  border 2px solid $color6
  background-color $color5
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50px;
  box-shadow 4px 4px 8px #aaa
  .title1
    height 53px
    width 100%
    border-bottom 1px solid $color6
    color white
    background-color $color6
```

I created the function to animate div's dimension when I hover it 
so I want to call it with hover event :

```js
    'hover div#container1' : 'enlargeSelectionOn("container1")'
```

But it's doesn't work! I know there's something wrong with my code

when I call it with no parameters like this

```js
  'hover div#container' : 'enlargeSelectionOn'
```

it works correctly

But in this case i'm forced to call the selected div inside my function

```
enlargeSelectionOn : () ->
  $('div#container1').stop().animate 
    width:450
    height:510
    1000
```

I want to use parameters because i'm going to use this function for differents div containers.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Your question lacks some context (html part).

Comment: I wanna just call my function with hover event ! that could be easy with no parametrs function but with parametrs I don't know the correct syntax to do it

Comment: Use `=` to assign to variables. `:` should *only* be used to assign Object keys. Here you're making an (unnamed) object instead of assigning a function to `enlargeSelectionOn`.

Comment: Are you using some sort of framework? You say that you're binding events with `'hover div#container1' : 'enlargeSelectionOn("container1")'` but what is binding the events?

Comment: @mu is too short I think that i find a part of solution ! it's impossible to call a function with parameters with this way so I must use currentTarget inside my function to say that my parameter is my target inside the declared function ! By the way I'm using backbone as framework

Comment: The solution is in using DOM elements that allows me to you use one parameter and i'm not even forced to call it in my event ! Thank you all of you

Comment: You should have included the backbone.js tag, that's pretty important information. Backbone allows anonymous functions in `events` so you could say `'hover div#container1' : function() { this.enlargeSelectionOn("container1") }`. I'd probably go with `currentTarget` and walk up the DOM to find what you're looking for though.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think the way you wrote the function is correct syntax. It should be:

```
enlargeSelectionOn = (zoneSelected) ->
  $(zoneSelected).stop().animate 
    width:450
    height:510
    1000
```

To call this function on a hover event, you'll want to tell jQuery to call the function `enlargeSelectionOn` when your div is hovered on. To do this, use the following code:

```
$("div#container").hover(enlargeSelectionOn("container1"))
```

More on the hover function can be found [in the jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/hover/).

Comment: Thank you for your response but the way I wrote the function is correct because it works for other functions without parameters and even the way I call the function still correct with no parametrs functions ! I don't know the correct syntax to call function with parametres

Comment: @L.Ezz Your function may be correct, but you're not assigning it to `enlargeSelectionOn`. Look at the generated output.

Comment: Oh, ok. @L.Ezz to call the function with parameters, say `'hover div#container' : enlargeSelectionOn("container1")` This should call the enlargeSelectionOn function when `div#container` is hovered on.

Comment: @user2367593: Are you sure about that? That would call `enlargeSelectionOn` when that object was defined, not when the hover event is triggered.